# Error: Attempt to create 2x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I have the following input file

```
gdalinfo SAVI_v2_T_0006_0006_savi.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: SAVI_v2_T_0006_0006_savi.tif
Size is 4308, 208
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
Origin = (742430.000000000000000,5870860.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (15.000000000000000,-15.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  742430.000, 5870860.000) ( 12d36'26.78"E, 52d55'57.16"N)
Lower Left  (  742430.000, 5867740.000) ( 12d36'18.40"E, 52d54'16.39"N)
Upper Right (  807050.000, 5870860.000) ( 13d33'57.69"E, 52d53'58.27"N)
Lower Right (  807050.000, 5867740.000) ( 13d33'47.10"E, 52d52'17.62"N)
Center      (  774740.000, 5869300.000) ( 13d 5' 8.33"E, 52d54'10.83"N)
Band 1 Block=4308x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=1.175494351e-38
```

And I would like to decrease its size by `1024x`. I specify the target resolution for `gdalwarp` to be `30720` = 15 (pixel size in meters) * 1024 as follows:

```
gdalwarp -tr 30720 30720 SAVI_v2_T_0006_0006_savi.tif out.tif
```

and get

`ERROR 1: Attempt to create 2x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.`

I suppose that formally the above command is correct but

- why those `208` pixels are squashed into `0` pixels instead of `1` pixel?
- how to deal with this situation?
- is there any other *reliable* way to reduce image size by an arbitrary scale factor?

Comment: what about gdal_translate -outsize 1024% 0 .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (although not perfect) is to utilize ImageMagic:

```
convert SAVI_v2_T_0006_0006_savi.tif -scale 0.09765625% out.tif
```

It does make the output file of size `4x1`

A drawback is that it does not preserve all GeoTIFF metadata:

```
gdalinfo out.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: out.tif
Size is 4, 1
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_DOCUMENTNAME=out.tif
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,    1.0)
Upper Right (    4.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (    4.0,    1.0)
Center      (    2.0,    0.5)
Band 1 Block=4x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=1
  Color Table (RGB with 2 entries)
    0: 0,0,0,255
    1: 255,255,255,255
```

One can write a Python script that restores the georeferencing of the output file.

Comment: Re-constructs rather than restores because of the changes in pixel size, but otherwise yes.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the -outsize option of gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html.

> **-outsize xsize[%]|0 ysize[%]|0:**
>
> Set the size of the output file. Outsize is in pixels and lines unless '%' is attached in which case it is as a fraction of the input
> image size. Starting with GDAL 2.0, if one of the 2 values is set to
> 0, its value will be determined from the other one, while maintaining
> the aspect ratio of the source dataset.

```
gdal_translate -outsize 0.09765625% 0 SAVI_v2_T_0006_0006_savi.tif out.tif
```

Without trying I can't say if gdal_translate is willing to push your 208 pixels into 1 pixel if they actually can fill only 0.2 pixels. At least I would not call it as a bug if it emits a reasonable error message.

Comment: I did not call that a bug :)

Comment: `gdal_translate -outsize 0.09765625% 0 SAVI_v2_T_0006_0006_savi.tif out.tif`
Input file size is 4308, 208
ERROR 5: Attempt to create 4x0 dataset is illegal.

Comment: without specifying ysize = 0 it refuses to work

Comment: Of course, it reads also in the documentation. I will correct it.

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: Try -outsize 0 1 for minimum output. This is something theoretical and not your final goal, I guess.

Comment: I would like a relative size, not fixed...

Comment: Did you try it? It should make 1 as width and height relative to that. Otherwise increase your outputsize, pixels are integers. Or are ready for changing the pixel size as well?

Comment: this will not do since I iterate programmatically over different files; seems like this is a special case - I must check if the result will 0 pixels in width/height or use an alternative way

Comment: Yes, I agree that images with data for filling less than one pixel are special cases when it comes to geospatial images. But I suppose it does not require much scripting to check the computed size and add +1 to width and/or height if needed.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution - to add some checks. I've added an alternative answer just to keep a comprehensive set of possible solutions in this thread.